# C#. Winfroms. Как называется событие при увеличении размера окна?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как называется событие при нажатии на эту кнопку?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: См. `Resize`, `SizeChanged`, `ClientSizeChanged`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Событие называется `Resize`

Для обработки случая с максимизацией размера окна внутри обработчика события `Resize` можно добавить проверку:

```
if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
{
    //Maximized!
}
```